# Can you connect to a LAN server without being on the same internet connection

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I was just wondering if you can make a LAN server then connect being across the world just using the ip address that you get to choose like this

Gamemode: blah, Op: blah

Port, IP Address

12345, 101.game.net

Answer (score 2):

I believe you would have to setup a dedicated server, and portforward/Hamachi to exit your LAN,and connect with IP/Port. Setting this up is relatively easy See [The Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server) article on it.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Good (and correct) answer. It is customary to include some of the content of linked sites, in case the link breaks in the future. If you can give a brief overview on how to set up a server, your answer can go from good to great.

Comment: The toughest part of this is shutting off the firewall for the port that needs to be opened, and/or routing through your local network. I host 3 vanilla MC servers off a Zotac ZBOX on my home lan. I opened the port up on the router and port forward from the router to the ZBOX. I run Fedora 19 on the ZBOX and have no trouble at all with int. and ext. connections. Internal connections are made to the ZBOX ip address ( 192.168.1.XXX ) while external connections connect through the outside IP of the router ( 70.141.262.XXX ). I have 3 servers running on different ports ( 25565, 25566, 25666 )

Answer (score 0):

The LAN server is intended to make accessing the server on your local network easy by allowing automatic server detection. That being said opening this up to outside connections defeats the purpose, but it entirely possible.

Probably the easiest way is to use a VPN (like Hamachi), if both parties connect to the VPN it's like they are on the same network, and LAN will work as normal. The process for doing this can be found [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Minecraft-Server-With-Hamachi).

The second way would be to port forward the port that the LAN server is running on, however since it chooses a new port each time it runs this is not a very good way to set things up.

Ultimately the best option is using the standard server, and port forwarding the default Minecraft server port. It's a little tricky to configure, but once you have it set up you won't need to worry about it anymore.

Comment: Hamachi does NOT work with regular LAN (i.e. "Singleplayer" -> "Open to LAN") games of Minecraft, as your link also states. Using the standard server is not the best, but the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Make you and your friends have Hamachi. Then, either you or your friend create a network, join the network. Click on your friend's network. Minimize it and open Minecraft. Click Multiplayer and type in your friend's IP. You are good to go. :)